# What does AVG(x) - 1 give us?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I've been studying for the query that my colleague coded it. For each product, we counted the prices in a specific time period to see how the price has changed for each product. Let's say that this is `"number_of_price"`.

And then, my colleague took the average of `"number_of_price"`, and then he formulated it like this:

`AVG(number_of_price) - 1 AS mean_price_updates`

But to be frank, I have no clue why this equation gives us the mean_price_updates.

Any idea?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  ..  and your expected  result

Comment: Sample data would really help understanding this question.  Although the (existing) answers make sense, they are making assumptions about what the underlying data looks like.  Actually, the best method is to ask your colleague.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 3 different prices in a time period, you have 2 updates, i think it's as simple as that.

This and the fact that `AVG(number_of_price - 1) = AVG(number_of_price) - 1`

Comment: EDIT: If it had said: 'we counted the DIFFERENT prices in a specific time period' it would be wrong, because updates back and force wouldn't be counted right.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the price change counts include the original price. E.g.:

```
+------+------------+-------+
| item | date       | price |
+------+------------+-------+
|    1 | 2020-01-01 | 10.00 |
|    1 | 2020-01-05 | 12.00 |
|    1 | 2020-01-16 | 13.00 |
|    2 | 2020-01-01 | 20.00 |
|    2 | 2020-01-27 | 23.00 |
+------+------------+-------+
```

That is three prices for product #1 and two prices for product #2. The avarage is 2.5 prices per product. Minus 1 is 1.5 price changes per product (two for #1 and 1 for #2).